# JAXB element is created when xsd with minoccurs=0 and nillable=true

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb2, wsdl2java

My xsd is having  2 fields defined with minouucrs=0 and nillable=true.When I generate Java object for this its generating JAXBElement instead of normal string.Is there any workaround to avoid JAXBElement.

```
JAXBElement<String> userId,
JAXBElement<String> userType.


**testSchema.xsd**
        <xs:complexType name="testSchema">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="age" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="userId" nillable="true"
                        type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="usertype" nillable="true"
                        type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

Why it's not creating normal XMLElement instaed of creating XMLElementRef?

I am using below dependency and plugin.

pom Dependencies

<dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
                    <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.13.1</version>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>schema1-generate</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema/testschema</schemaDirectory>
                                <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                                <schemaIncludes>
                                    <include>**/*.wsdl</include>
                                    <include>*.wsdl</include>
                                </schemaIncludes>
                                <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>
```

Also I have defined bindings.xjb under src/main/resources

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
               xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="/schema/testschema/*.xsd"
                   node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

Why it's generating JAXBElement instead of normal String for these two fields.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Dmitriy When we have both minouucrs=0 and nillable=true in XSD it will generate JAXBElement to avoid this we need to remove either of the one.

Comment: thanks for your answer I am using `generateElementProperty="false"` property when generating POJO objects from XSD scheme and it is working like a charm.

Comment: @Dmitriy nice to here.